# Can moderators close questions without having the required number of votes?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, moderation, reopen-closed, privileges

I know that members with high reputations can get involve in moderator activities.  For example, I have recently started to review and vote on posts that have been put into the review queue. I have seen that questions that get votes to close seem to require a certain number of votes before being put on hold and entering the review queue.  It appears that a moderator can put a post on hold without any other votes.  Am I right about this? Can members with high reputation who are not moderators do this also?

Another observation I have about the review queue is that any edit of a post can kick it back into the review queue for voting to reopen.  To reduce the burden on the moderators and others who vote in the review queue shouldn't there be some restriction so that the edit has to have some new content to be put back into the review queue?

Comment: Once again see accessible documentation: http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators

Comment: What do you think I am missing?

Comment: You seem to be asking questions when often the answers are already documented. You did this with a question on bounties, for example.

Comment: I think meta is for discussion we only have so much time to devote to the site.  Others learn from these posts also.

Comment: Naturally I agree that Meta is for discussion. But questions about what is factual and already documented are less useful than discussion of genuine issues. The very good accepted answer below has one weakness in implying that answers to these points are to be sought in Meta posts, but most of what you've asked recently is documented on CV's own part of the site. You would get answers faster and more efficiently by starting with http://stats.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: +1 for @NickCox'es comments and -1 to this question because it "does not show any research effort" (I assume the other downvote had similar motivation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A single vote by a moderator is sufficient for *any* action: closing, reopening, deletion, undeletion. See [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189)

High reputation does not confer this ability. However, having a gold tag badge grants the user a [binding closing vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212) for *duplicate* on questions having that tag.

---

Regarding reopening, from [How do you reopen a closed question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36415):

> Editing the body of a question within five days of closure will add it to the Reopen Review queue, where people with the the ability to cast reopen votes will assess it. A question can only be added to the Reopen Review queue once per closure via editing.

So, the edit must change the post body (not just title or tags). The system is unable to judge whether the edit was significant. In my experience, an edit that does nothing but *remove*  content (distracting off-topic parts, or broken markup that makes the text unreadable) can make a question worth reopening.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the links.  In your last sentence did you really mean that just removing content can make a question worth reopening.  Shouldn't you consider why the post was closed in the first place.

Comment: One should consider everything. And it sometimes happens that, after everything is considered, an edit that _removed_ a part of a question makes it worth reopening. One example is when a question had several parts and was closed as too broad.

Comment: That makes sense.  I guess regarding editing to reopen I would like to find something other than just a to change that would keep a post out of the reopen queue.  I have many questions on this topic and you answered most of them.